# Adding a top header to UICollectionview that already has sections with headers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Assuming I have a UICollectionview with sections and items.
For each section I generate a header as the code below.

**Question:** How do I add a top header view to the collectionView itself
which is different than the section header demonstrate below (using objective-c, IB, Auto Layouts)

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionReusableView *reusableview = nil;




    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        HeaderCollectionReusableView *headerView = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];


        headerView.label1.text = "This is a section title";

        reusableview = headerView;
    }



    return reusableview;
}
```

Comment: Creating a view above the collection view with height = 0 and changing it programatically with auto layout, is an option for you?

Comment: Yes please, post an elaborate answer if you be as kind.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I would do those steps in order to accomplish it:**

1. In your story board, create a UIView and design it's subviews as you wish. Please make sure you're checking the `clipToBounds` checkbox for the UIView you've just created.
2. Create your constraints. My guess that it should with top 0, left 0, right 0 and of course height 0 (cause this is the initial state as you mentioned).
3. Create IBOutlet for the height constraint and connect it to the height constraint you've just created. Let's call it `viewHeaderHeightConstraint`.
4. When you want to show this view:

   ```
   self.viewHeaderHeightConstraint.constant = 50; // Or any other value
   [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
   ```
5. If you want to animate the height change:

   ```
   self.viewHeaderHeightConstraint.constant = 50; // Or any other value
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

       [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

   } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

       // Do something after completion

   }];
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Generate another header for first section with your current header view and a top header view in one view. Don't forget to return a bigger size in `collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:` for first section.

[image]